# Задать существующие поддомены в .htaccess, а несуществующие переадресовывать на 404

Tags: .htaccess

Сайт имеет не ограниченное количество субдоменов (указано * при создании субдомена). При это субдомен может быть любым.

Всего существует порядка 1200 поддоменов, которые ссылаются на одну папку (корень).

Нужно сделать проверку на существование домена, а все несуществующие перекидывать на 404.

Comment: они у вас в базе должны быть и скриптом проверять надо, есть или нет, и если нет, то 301 редирект.

Comment: к сожалению базы как таковой у сайта нет. Только PHP

Comment: воспользуйтесь тогда DBM файлом и директивой RewriteMap 
https://htmlweb.ru/php/htaccess-mod_rewrite-rewritemap.php